# Master grid cell value as sum of detail view cell values that has unbound type

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, master-detail, gridcontrol

I have grid control that has master-detail views. And in detail view I have unbounded column called `LinePrice`. and I need to represent sum of `LinePrice` in master column.
I used some samples but i'm getting error that

> "LinePrice" does not belong to the table

.
this is my question is any way to get sum of unbound column in master or not?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for your task depends on the place where you need to show your summary value. If you need to show it in a separate master view column, create an unbound column in your master view and populate it via the [CustomUnboundColumnData event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic.aspx) handler. In this event handler, calculate the summary value manually and pass it as the **e.Value** parameter.